# Define models in seperate file when using app factory flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a flask application where I am using the app factory method. I have a file in the application folder `__init__.py` which has the `create_app` function with the following code

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
    )

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/database'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if test_config == None:
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py',silent=True)
else:
    app.config.form_mapping(test_config)

from flaskr import models

try:
    os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
except OSError:
    pass

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    uname = db.Column(db.String(50))

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return json.dumps({'message':'hello','status':True})
@app.route('/getusers')
def getusers():
    u = User.query.get(1)
    return json.dumps({'uname':u.uname})

return app
```

What I want is to define the models in a seperate file. How can I do this?
I have tried defining in a seperate file and importing it. But the problem is the model inherits the `db.Model` which is then not available in the imported file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the creation of `db` object outside `create_app` without passing any `app` instance and use the `SQLAlchemy.init_app` method to configure and init. your `db` object, this way you can `import` it from any file:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
#...
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True)
    #...
    db.init_app(app)
```

More on this topic can be found at [flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/)

Answer (score 0):

I've fought with this problem a few hours too. Couldn't fix it until I came to the realization, that I have to return the app inside the `app.app_context()`

`model.py`:

```
from flask_user import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    email = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False,
                      unique=True)
   # ...
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)

    migrate = Migrate()

    from appname.model import db
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    with app.app_context():
        # Create all database tables
        db.create_all()

        import appname.routes

        # Apply the blueprints to the app
        from appname import bp1, bp2

        appname.register_blueprint(bp1.bp)
        appname.register_blueprint(bp2.bp)

        return app
```

Run with:

```
cd ~/Folder/Webapp
. appname/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=appname
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

(in Linux terminal)

or create this file and run it in python shell:

```
from appname import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```